# SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol when invoking SageMaker endpoint - SSL validation failed

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

```
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer

# Deploy the XGBoost model with CSVSerializer and JSONDeserializer
predictor = Xgboost_classifier.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
    endpoint_name='End-point-name',
    serializer=CSVSerializer(),
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer()
)

inference_test_csv = X_test_sagemaker_inference.to_csv(index=False, header=False)
# Make predictions using the deployed endpoint
predictions = predictor.predict(inference_test_csv)

# Decode the JSON response (assuming predictions are in JSON format)
result = json.loads(predictions)
print(result)
```

SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://runtime.sagemaker.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/endpoints/End-point-name/invocations EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2426)

Comment: Are you using a built-in algorithm to train the model? Where is the code being run (notebook on SageMaker, local notebook)?

Comment: Yes, I am using Sagemaker's XGBOOST model and the code is on a Sagemaker notebook.